# Pandas groupby + resample first is really slow - since version 0.22

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a piece of code that groups a dataframe and runs `resample('1D').first()` for each group. Since I upgraded to 0.22.0, it runs much slower.

**Setup code**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import string


# set up some data
DATE_U = 50

STR_LEN = 10
STR_U = 50

N = 500

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
def get_rand_string():
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(letters, size=STR_LEN))

dates = np.random.randint(0, 100000000, size=DATE_U)
strings = [get_rand_string() for _ in range(STR_U)]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': np.random.choice(dates, N),
    'string': np.random.choice(strings, N),
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('date')

print('Shape: {}'.format(df.shape))
print(df.head())
print('\nUnique strings: {}'.format(df['string'].nunique()))
print('Unique dates: {}'.format(df.index.nunique()))
```

**(Prints)**:

```
Shape: (500, 1)
                       string
date                           
1973-02-07 19:57:43  wafadvlvty
1973-02-27 03:43:02  shofwwdhtu
1972-04-25 18:11:20  xwbbpwtsfj
1970-09-03 18:00:59  zkxwnqgrqp
1971-03-18 10:09:44  ofsaxqprdx

Unique strings: 50
Unique dates: 50
```

**Testing the groupby + resample.first**:

```
%%timeit -n 3 -r 3

def __apply(g):   
    g = g.resample('1D').first()
    return g

print('Pandas version: {}'.format(pd.__version__))

dfg = df.groupby('string').apply(__apply)
```

For Pandas 0.21.0:

```
Pandas version: 0.21.0
118 ms ± 1.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 3 loops each)
```

For Pandas 0.22.0:

```
Pandas version: 0.22.0
3 loops, best of 3: 2.3 s per loop
```

Which is about 20 times slower. My questions is why is that? And is there a way to make this equally fast in 0.22.0?

Answer (score -1):

Use .head(1) instead as the following

```
g = g.resample('1D').head(1)
```

Comment: That does not even work - `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'head'`

Comment: @Ferrard please check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head where it says "Return first n rows of each group." Your g needs to be a GroupBy Pandas Object

Comment: I don't see how this is answering the question. My `g` is ***not*** a GroupBy object - I am talking here about performance of `resample`, not grouping. If you really have an answer to the question then either post code that works or be very clear about what modifications are required. That would be my advise for your future Stackoverflow posts too.