# Need to optimize/avoid pandas .resample in groupby calls (need to bring this down to <60s for 1.4k rows -- currently >160s)

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series entries that I need to resample. On the more extreme end of things I've imagined that someone might generate data for 15 months -- this tends to be about 1300 records (about 5 location entries to every 2 metric entries). But after resampling to 15 minute intervals, the full set is about 41000 rows.

My data is less than a couple of dozen columns right now, so 20 column * 40k ≈ 800k values that need to be calculated .. this seems like I should be able to get my time down to below 10 seconds really. I've done an initial profile and it looks like the bottleneck is mostly in one pair of pandas methods for resampling that I am calling -- and they are amazingly slow! Its to the point where I am wondering if there is something wrong ..why would pandas be so slow to resample?

This produces a timeout in google cloud functions. That's what I need to avoid.

There's two sets of data: location and metric. Sample location data might look like this:

```
location    bar     girlfriends     grocers     home    lunch   park    relatives   work 
date    user                                
2018-01-01 00:00:01     0ce65715-4ec7-4ca2-aab0-323c57603277    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

sample metric data might look like this:

```
user    date    app     app_id  metric
0   4fb488bc-aea0-4f1e-9bc8-d7a8382263ef    2018-01-01 01:30:43     app_2   c2bfd6fb-44bb-499d-8e53-4d5af522ad17    0.02
1   6ca1a9ce-8501-49f5-b7d9-70ac66331fdc    2018-01-01 04:14:59     app_2   c2bfd6fb-44bb-499d-8e53-4d5af522ad17    0.10
```

I need to union those two subsets to a single ledger, with columns for each location *name* and each app. The values in apps are samples of constants, so I need to "connect the dots". The values in locations are location change events, so I need to keep repeating the same value until the next change event. In all, it like this:

```
    app_1   app_2   user    bar     grocers     home    lunch   park    relatives   work
date                                        
2018-01-31 00:00:00     0.146250    0.256523    4fb488bc-aea0-4f1e-9bc8-d7a8382263ef    0   0   1   0   0   0   0
2018-01-31 00:15:00     0.146290    0.256562    4fb488bc-aea0-4f1e-9bc8-d7a8382263ef    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

This code does that, but needs to be optimized. What are the weakest links here? I've added basic sectional profiling:

```
import time
start = time.time()

locDf = locationDf.copy()
locDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# convert location data to "15 minute interval" rows
locDfs = {}
for user, user_loc_dc in locDf.groupby('user'):
    locDfs[user] = user_loc_dc.resample('15T').agg('max').bfill()

aDf = appDf.copy()
aDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)

print("section1:", time.time() - start)

userLocAppDfs = {}
for user, a2_df in aDf.groupby('user'):    
    start = time.time()

    # per user, convert app data to 15m interval
    userDf = a2_df.resample('15T').agg('max')

    print("section2.1:", time.time() - start)
    start = time.time()

    # assign metric for each app to an app column for each app, per user   
    userDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
    userDf = pd.crosstab(index=userDf['date'], columns=userDf['app'], values=userDf['metric'], aggfunc=np.mean).fillna(np.nan, downcast='infer')

    userDf['user'] = user

    userDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
    userDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    print("section2.2:", time.time() - start)
    start = time.time()

    # reapply 15m intervals now that we have new data per app
    userLocAppDfs[user] = userDf.resample('15T').agg('max')

    print("section2.3:", time.time() - start)
    start = time.time()

    # assign location data to location columns per location, creates a "1" at the 15m interval of the location change event in the location column created    
    loDf = locDfs[user]
    loDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
    loDf = pd.crosstab([loDf.date, loDf.user], loDf.location)
    loDf.reset_index(inplace=True)

    loDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    loDf.drop('user', axis=1, inplace=True)

    print("section2.4:", time.time() - start)
    start = time.time()

    # join the location crosstab columns with the app crosstab columns per user
    userLocAppDfs[user] = userLocAppDfs[user].join(loDf, how='outer')
    # convert from just "1" at each location change event followed by zeros, to "1" continuing until next location change
    userLocAppDfs[user] = userLocAppDfs[user].resample('15T').agg('max')
    userLocAppDfs[user]['user'].fillna(user, inplace=True)

    print("section2.5:", time.time() - start)
    start = time.time()

    for loc in locationDf[locationDf['user'] == user].location.unique():

        # fill location NaNs
        userLocAppDfs[user][loc] = userLocAppDfs[user][loc].replace(np.nan, 0)

    print("section3:", time.time() - start)
    start = time.time()


    # fill app NaNs
    for app in a2_df['app'].unique():
        userLocAppDfs[user][app].interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside', inplace=True)       
        userLocAppDfs[user][app].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

    print("section4:", time.time() - start)
```

results:

```
section1: 41.67342448234558
section2.1: 11.441165685653687
section2.2: 0.020460128784179688
section2.3: 5.082422733306885
section2.4: 0.2675948143005371
section2.5: 40.296404123306274
section3: 0.0076410770416259766
section4: 0.0027387142181396484
section2.1: 11.567803621292114
section2.2: 0.02080368995666504
section2.3: 7.187351703643799
section2.4: 0.2625312805175781
section2.5: 40.669641733169556
section3: 0.0072269439697265625
section4: 0.00457453727722168
section2.1: 11.773712396621704
section2.2: 0.019629478454589844
section2.3: 6.996192693710327
section2.4: 0.2728455066680908
section2.5: 45.172399282455444
section3: 0.0071871280670166016
section4: 0.004514217376708984
```

Both "big" sections have calls to `resample` and `agg('max')`.

### notes:

I found this problem from 12 months ago: [Pandas groupby + resample first is really slow - since version 0.22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239652/pandas-groupby-resample-first-is-really-slow-since-version-0-22) -- seems like perhaps resample() in groupby is broken currently.

Comment: Have you done any profiling to figure out the worst bottlenecks?  Always figure out where the actual bottlenecks are before trying to optimize them away.  I recently had a set of MySQL queries that went from minutes to seconds once I narrowed down the problem to one query needing an index added to a column.

Comment: I'm finishing that now -- early result -- the .agg('max').bfill() at the top by itself takes about 40 seconds -- and apparently I was wrong, total is closer to 200s.